# How to fetch data values from table if checkboxes are selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a table like

```
        <table>
           <thead>
            ...
           </thead>

            <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td><input id="1" type="checkbox"/></td>
                ..
                <td class="email">esha@gmail.com</td>
              </tr>

               <tr>
               <td><input id="2" type="checkbox"/></td>
                ..
                <td class="email">Nisha@gmail.com</td>
              </tr>
             ...  
           </tbody>
        </table>
        ...
        ...
        <input type="button" onclick="saveAndSend()" />

           function saveAndSend()
               {
                  var ele = $("tbody").find('input');
                  if(ele.is(':checked')){
                   var studentList = "1,2";
                   var emailAddresses = "esha@gmail.com, Nisha@gmail";
                  });
               }
```

Now in jQuery, I want to fetch all id's of selected/checked checkboxes in table 
and put them in a variable and fetch email addresses of selected/checked checkboxes in table and put them in another variable.

Please help me!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate the [`:checked`](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) checkboxes and then use DOM traversal methods to target the `email` element.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#saveAndSend').on('click', function() {
    //Iterate and create an array
    var arr = $("table").find(':checkbox:checked').map(function() {
      var $this = $(this)
      return {
        id: $this.attr('id'),
        email: $this.closest('tr').find('.email').text()
      }
    }).get();

    var ids = arr.map(function(e) {
      return e.id
    }).join(',');
    
    var emails = arr.map(function(e) {
      return e.email
    }).join(',');
    console.log(ids, emails);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="1" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td class="email">esha@gmail.com</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input id="2" type="checkbox" /></td>
      <td class="email">Nisha@gmail.com</td>
  </tbody>
</table>
<button type="button" id="saveAndSend">Send</button>
```

Also note, as you are using jQuery use unobtrusive event handler.

References

- [`.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/)
- [`.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)
- [`.find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/)

Comment: Great solution... Thanks but I need to put them in variable with "," seperator and in the above solution it is being stored in array... if it is possible for u, please convert array into two variables.

Comment: @Nida, You can extract information from the array, Updated answer

Answer (score 1):

It might help you.

```js
function saveAndSend()
               {
                 var ele = $("tbody").find('input');
                 var saveInto=[]; 
                  $.each(ele, function( index, val ) {
                    if($(val).is(':checked')){
                      var id=$(val).attr('id');
                      var email=$(val).closest('tr').find('.email').text();
                      var temp={id:id,email:email};
                      saveInto.push(temp);
                    }
                      
                      
                  });
                  console.log(saveInto);
               }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
           <thead>
           </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
               <td><input id="1" type="checkbox"/></td>     
                <td class="email">esha@gmail.com</td>
              </tr>
               <tr>
               <td><input id="2" type="checkbox"/></td>
                <td class="email">Nisha@gmail.com</td>
              </tr>
           </tbody>
        </table>
<input type="button" onclick="saveAndSend()" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve your goal with plain javascript this way quit simply this way:

```
checkedEmails = []
chboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]')
emails = document.querySelectorAll('.email')
checkedEmails = []

for (var i = 0; i < chboxes.length; i++)
{

    if (chboxes[i].checked)
        checkedEmails.push(emails[i].innerHTML)

}
```

and then you will have your desired emails in the variable checkedEmails

Comment: I do believe my way is the simplest from all the offered answers and it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
  var studentList =[];
  var emailAddresses=[];
  $('table tr').each(function (i, row) {
  var tr =$(row);
  var chk= tr.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')
  console.log(chk)
  if(chk){
      emailAddresses.push(tr.find('.email').text())
      studentList.push(tr.find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('id'))
      console.log(emailAddresses);
      console.log(studentList);        
     }
  });
```

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/H7deSTemD8mWryJNMOg7?p=preview)